# Removing a line inside a <pre> from the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, pre

When I remove a line from a `<pre>` tag the rest of the lines below it don't move up like they would if using a standard `<div>` or any other element.

You can see an example of this at http://jsfiddle.net/NN6LC/

Has anybody encountered this issue before or knows how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must remove the linebreak after the line too.

http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/KgYyp/

Answer (score 4):

You are removing the span, but the newline is still there.

And technically  you are not even allowed to have `<span>`s in a `<pre>`.

From http://lib.ru/WEBMASTER/elements.html#PRE:

> **Elements Allowed Within...**
>
> elements `<A>` `<HR>` `<BR>` and parsed character data.

The way around it is to use a `<div>` instead of a `<pre>` and set styles on the div to make it look like a a `<pre>`.

EDIT: Someone else had posted the answer below, then deleted their answer. I do not know why, since it was a good answer. But this is how they did it:

If you don't care about `<span>`s not technically being allowed, you can manually remove it and the newline like this: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/KgYyp/

```
function removeLine() {
    var line=$('pre span.line_1');
    if(line.length) {
        if(line[0].nextSibling && line[0].nextSibling.nodeType == 3) {
            line[0].parentNode.removeChild(line[0].nextSibling);
        }

    }
    line.remove();
}
```

This will check for a newline after the element before removing it, and remove the newline too if it exists.

Comment: Thanks, we need to keep the `pre` to preserve the tabs/spacing so we can't just style the div.

Comment: @fire, I updated the code to show a non-hacky way to remove the newline from the div.

Comment: Looks like @Dr.Molle put his answer back. I would accept his, it looks like his solves your issue.

Comment: Yeh he deleted it as I was going to :-p thanks for your help!

Comment: That HTML reference doc is from 1995. I'm pretty sure that a span in a pre is perfectly legitimate these days.

Answer (score 0):

What curious behaviour.  Here's a way around it, but I admit it's not entirely satisfactory.

Add the following CSS:

```
pre {white-space: normal}
pre span {display: block}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/tG8V6/ for a working version.